# Possible way of getting address from checkout and make it default

Tags: magento, onestepcheckout

i'm trying to get address from checkout page for a registered customer. on the checkout page I have a form that a user has to fill in with address info. Now the trick is to get that address displayed on the account dashboard.

I did try to get the address on the quote on .phtml here is my code

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quote_billing = $quote->getBillingAddress();

echo $quote_billing
```

Is there any other possible way to get and address from a session

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

foreach ($customer->getAddresses() as $address) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($address->getData());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do what you did and just do getData() on the $quote_billing.  That should provide you with the data that you need to pull.